# Jetty 9.4 does unnecessary redirection

Tags: java, jetty-9

After I upgraded from jetty 9.3 to 9.4 I noticed that jetty does a redirection from http://localhost:port/ to http://localhost:port/index.html

Under `./src/main/webapp` there is the index.html, so locally it is working fine, but the redirect itself is a problem as I use an nginx as proxy and the localhost of the redirection causes problems. Also the redirection seems unnecessary to me.

This is the code I use to start jetty:

```
    int httpPort = 9000;

    ResourceHandler resHandler = new ResourceHandler();
    resHandler.setDirectoriesListed(false);
    resHandler.setResourceBase("./src/main/webapp");

    Server server = new Server();
    ServletContextHandler servHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    servHandler.setContextPath("/");
    servHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new InvalidRequestServlet()), "/*");

    FilterHolder guiceFilter = new FilterHolder(injector.getInstance(GuiceFilter.class));
    servHandler.addFilter(guiceFilter, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));

    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory());
    http.setPort(httpPort);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{http});
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{resHandler,servHandler});
    server.setHandler(handlers);
    server.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague [found the solution](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/pull/1055):

```
resHandler.setRedirectWelcome(false);
```